# Rest Operator With Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, rest, operator-keyword

```js
const sum = (function() {
  "use strict";
  return function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };
})();
console.log(sum(1,2,3,4))
```

this code is working as expected
but how some one please explain how this js code working

Comment: Here is how: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: You already know that it's called rest syntax, so presumably you know something about it. What in particular do you not understand? What *do* you understand?

Answer (score 1):

With all noise removed, the code is

```
const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

which is

- accept any number of arguments (`...args`)
- take these arguments as an array (`args`)
- apply `reduce` to it
- initialize the accumulator to `0`
- on each `reduce` step, add the current value `b` to the accumulator `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
...args  //The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.
```

[image]

[Play here](http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#code=const%20sum%20%3D%20%28function%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%22use%20strict%22%3B%0A%20%20return%20function%20sum%28...args%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20args.reduce%28%28a,%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20b,%200%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%29%28%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28sum%281,2,3,4%29%29&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D)